# InvalidCastException Error caused by DB row?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I have the following C# code:

```
private DataSet GetSummaryData(DataSet ds)
{
    DataSet dsSum = new DataSet();
    DataTable dtSum = new DataTable();


    DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[0];

    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dataTable.Columns.Count > 1)
            {
                dtSum.Columns.Add("Line Number", typeof(int));
                dtSum.Columns.Add("Throughput", typeof(int));
                dtSum.Columns.Add("Lost Time", typeof(int));
                dtSum.Columns.Add("Pounds Made", typeof(int));
                dtSum.Columns.Add("Pounds Lost", typeof(int));
                dtSum.Columns.Add("Yearly Potential", typeof(int));

                //Getting the Subtotal of PoundsMade based on the Line Number column
                //C# linq query
                var query = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                            group row by row.Field<int>("Linenumber") into grp
                            orderby grp.Key
                            select new
                            {
                                Linenumber = grp.Key,
                                TotalPoundsMade = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Pounds Made")),
                                AvgThroughput = grp.Average(r => r.Field<int>("Throughput")),
                                TotalLostTime = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Lost Time")),
                                AvgPercDown = grp.Average(r => r.Field<int>("% Down")),
                                TotalPoundsLost = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Pounds Lost")),
                                TotalYearlyPotential = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Yearly Potential")),
                            };

                foreach (var grp in query)
                {
                    dtSum.Rows.Add(grp.Linenumber, grp.TotalPoundsMade,grp.AvgThroughput,grp.TotalLostTime, 
                        grp.AvgPercDown, grp.TotalPoundsLost, grp.TotalYearlyPotential);
                    string strXML = null;
                        strXML = strXML + "<set name='" + grp.Linenumber + "' value='" + grp.TotalPoundsMade + "'/>";

                }

            }
        }
    }
    dsSum.Tables.Add(dtSum);
    return dsSum;
}
```

This code, as you can see, uses Linq to access my database. The SQL is:

```
SELECT 
    PDT.LineNumber, 
    SUM(prdt.PoundsMade) as 'Pounds Made',
    CAST(ROUND(SUM(CAST(prdt.PoundsMade as DECIMAL))/ (MIN(LSA.AvailableHRS) - SUM(PDT.DownTimeHrs)),0,0) as int) 
as 'Throughput',
    SUM(PDT.DownTimeHrs) as 'Lost Time',
    Str(ROUND(CAST(SUM(PDT.DownTimeHrs) as DECIMAL)/CAST(MIN(LSA.AvailableHRS) as DECIMAL) * 100,0), 3,0) + '%' 
as '% Down', 
    CAST((ROUND(SUM(CAST(prdt.PoundsMade as DECIMAL))/ (MIN(LSA.AvailableHRS) - SUM(PDT.DownTimeHrs)),0,0))  * 
(SUM(PDT.DownTimeHrs)) as int) as 'Pounds Lost',
    CAST(ROUND(SUM(CAST(prdt.PoundsMade as DECIMAL))/ (MIN(LSA.AvailableHRS) - SUM(PDT.DownTimeHrs)),0,0) as int) * 
24 * 365  as 'Yearly Potential' 

FROM  
    rpt_Line_Shift_ProdDownTime AS PDT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN rpt_Line_Shift_Prod AS Prdt  
    ON  PDT.LineNumber = Prdt.LineNumber
    and PDT.ShiftNumber = Prdt.ShiftNumber 
    and PDT.WorkDate = Prdt.WorkDate 
    INNER JOIN rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs AS LSA
    ON  PDT.LineNumber = LSA.LineNumber 
    and PDT.ShiftNumber = LSA.ShiftNumber
WHERE 
    PDT.WorkDate BETWEEN @p_From_Date and @p_Through_Date 
GROUP BY  
    PDT.LineNumber, PDT.ShiftNumber 
ORDER BY 
    PDT.LineNumber, PDT.ShiftNumber
```

The hangup seems to be that the '% Down' row is not casting correctly. It is a decimal type in SQL, and it makes sense that it would therefore be castable to type int in C#. Unfortunately, when I run the program, I receive a "InvalidCastException" message. Note that, if I comment out the following C# snippets:

"AvgPercDown = grp.Average(r => r.Field("% Down"))," and "grp.AvgPercDown,"

the code "works". Of course, that's not a fix. /shrug

Any thoughts? How can I fix this? I have tried casting the '% Down' row (in the C# code) as something other than int (such as double), but it doesn't like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it has been my experience that Oracle decimal does not correctly convert to C# Int, when using OracleDataReaders I have to get the value as a decimal and convert that to Int. Some newer versions of the ODAC seem to have corrected parts of this issue.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to fix it by casting the "% Down" field explicitly in the .SQL file. So, it does the calculation and then converts to int. Not the most elegant solution, but it gives me the results I need.

Comment: yeah, I've extended the OracleDataReader to convert decimals to different number types in C#.  But I agree, we shouldn't need to.

Comment: The funny thing is, I've been using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studio 2012. You would think, since C# is a Microsoft technology and SQL Server is also a Microsoft technology, that they would play nicely with each other. Apparently not. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

looks like "% Down" is a decimal value. In which case you should use:

```
AvgPercDown = grp.Average(r => r.Field<decimal>("% Down")),
```

Comment: I actually tried that, and the error is still popping up. I even tried a statement like:  "AvgPercDown = grp.Average(r => (r.IsNull("% Down") ? 0 : r.Field<decimal>("% Down")))".

That, of course, took care of any possible null values. I was thinking possible null values might be the issue. (And that was another error I was getting.) However, it didn't end up fixing this.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when you try my suggestion?

Comment: Also, what do you get from `dtSum.Columns["% Down"].DataType.Name`?